# Loop condition with operators

Tags: tcl

I am not experienced in Tcl language. I am trying to run a loop and trying to write output to an output file. My loop condition is not generating any output. I have double checked my inputs they seem to be correct. Is my syntax for end condition is correct ?  Instead of `&&` if I use just `$j >83` the it's works fine. ( I have attached a snipped on my code below, I have issue in the first line of my code).

```
for {set j 1} { $j > 83 && $j < 104 } {incr j}
 {

    set sel [atomselect top "resid $j and name CA"]
    mol reanalyze top
    set structs [$sel get structure]
    if {[lindex $structs ] == "H"} 
    {
        incr count
    }
    puts -nonewline $output $j
    puts  -nonewline $output "   "
    puts $output $structs
 }
```

Comment: Is the line break after {incr j} a typo? If not,  you have a syntax error right there. (Same with the if.)

Comment: Also,  no index is given in the invocation of lindex, which means that all of $structs is compared to H each time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the obvious syntax errors are corrected…

The `for` command stops when the condition expression clause evaluates to false. On the first time through, you first run the setup clause (`set j 1`) and then checks the condition (`$j > 83 && $j < 104`) which indeed evaluates to false because 1 is not between 83 and 104, so the `for` stops before running the body of the loop.

You might be happier with:

```
for {set j 84} {$j < 104} {incr j} {
    # The rest of your loop body here...
}
```

In more complex cases, you defining a basic loop and then put a separate skip rule within the body:

```
for {set j 1} {$j <= 200} {incr j} {
    if {!($j > 83 && $j < 104)} {
        # Start the next loop round immediately
        continue
    }

    # The rest of your loop body here...
}
```

But in this case… just loop over the right range to start out with.